# Navigation formatting

Tags: html, css

http://www.ryanbenson.info/wordpress/

The navigation is a two layer image fading on hover. Black when you hover, white when you don't.

The images are held in the .hoveringnav with classes "top" (the top white image) and "bottom" (the bottom dark image)

They're aligned with eachother just fine, and they worked really well until I upgraded the images last night. Now, the images are all over the place.

I'm not even sure what I did. Do you? It's all in my CSS somewhere, that I went wrong. (All in the header, nav, and hoveringnav)

Comment: What do you mean by pictures aligned? What is precisely your problem? When you conclude your question with "Anything helps" you sound like you doesn't even know what your problem is.

Comment: Take a look at my navigation and gather what you think is wrong. The images need to be post ironed at the same height

Comment: Ok, sorry for the first comment, but you gave little info and that problem wasn't eye catching. The icons on the navbar are not align properly. Gonna find a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing these if you want to bottom-align the images on the navigation bar.

```
.hoveringnav {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0px 24px;
    width: 0px;
    transition: 2s;
    position: relative;
}

.hoveringnav img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

if they get too near the text, try changing this:

```
.hoveringnav img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I was out of ideas, thank you so much!